# Getting Websites's root directory

Tags: php

In php there is any method to get a separate website's root directory?I know only the ftp details of the website.In my program i want to login to the ftp server using ftp details and create a folder in the website's root directory.For that I want to know the root directory of the website.Using `ftp_nlist()` it shows all directories.From that i want to identify which is the root directory of the website.How can i do this?

These are the steps in my script

1. Login to the ftp server using `ftp_connect()` and `ftp_login()`
2. Fetch the website's root directory
3. create a folder in that directory

Comment: Website's root directory... do you mean the file path of the `index.php` ?

Comment: Yes.But in some server there is more than one folder containing index.php.So i want to identify which is the correct root directory

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have access to FTP, thus you can use this line to find out the absolute path of the `index.php`:

```
$directory = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Comment: Using this it displays my website's root directory.I want another website's root directory which i know its ftp details.

Comment: In separate web server you mean ? Then you PHP's FTP library to upload the above script to remote server and obtain the result. Or, if you have the FTP server credentials, you already know the path.

Comment: Yes,in a separate web server.

Comment: No,It displays my website's root directory

Comment: Can you elaborate what you have tried using the script by **editing your question** ?

Comment: Yes,I added steps in my script

Comment: Noted, FYI, you can directly create a directory using FTP command, specifically [ftp_mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mkdir.php)